# Opening an .sdx file

Tags: file, visual-studio-2010, download, dreamspark

I am having a lot of difficulty downloading an SDX file. I am trying to download Visual studio 2012 from a website that offers it free to students (DreamSpark). I have managed to download the installation pack (SDM file). Whenever I download the SDX file it says it needs to know what program should be used to open it. I've tried everything, including Apple QuickTime Player. In its current format, I cannot open it to begin downloading files as the instructions on the website say I should do.

Any help from someone who has come across this before would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try SDM itself to open it?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you'll need to install the Software Download Manager (SDM) from DreamSpark. This is done by logging into your DreamSpark account and downloading it directly from DreamSpark. Once installed, it'll be associated with the .SDX file extension, and will be able to open the file(s) as needed. I Know, because as a DreamSpark user myself, I have done this before.

In Linux -- [EDIT] In Linux, you use Linux-SDM-Downloader which is available from a github repository: https://github.com/RadekSimkanic/Linux-SDM-Downloader. From my own personal usage, it opens the sdx file and allows you to download the files from DreamSpark.

Answer (score -1):

If you have not got the Manager program download that first

That will solve the SDM problem your having then I would try re launching the installer for your downloaded piece of software which in you case was visual studio 2012 as that will pick the SDX file up

If it asks what program try and hit browse or on modern systems e.g. 8.1 10 for Windows 10 it will say look for another app on this PC basically the same thing

Try looking for a folder that will contain the SDN installer

Then if you manage to find it try re launching the visual studio 2012 installer and if it runs sit back and wait for a bit

Then all being well you should be good to setup 2012 Visual Studio and enjoy it forever and forever

Comment: there is nothing helpful about this answer, that I can find. And, I always try to find something good/useful to say to encourage others to answer. On this one, I'm at a loss... so -1.